# own hide class method using javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, hide

i am making my own class method using javascript

```
.hide = function() {
this.each(function(index){
    this.style.display="none";
});
};
```

but this not works.
Can you tell me what i do wrong?

Comment: Are you using jQuery. This is jQuery style.

Comment: no i do not want to use jquery. i have tried to write it, but it not allowed to publish this post with that text

Comment: Are you trying to add method to DOM Element? This is not advised. .hide in itself is invalid function name. Dot prefix is not allowed. Secondly, you should try passing a DOM element as parameter to hide function. I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is not advised to add functions to existing Objects in Javascript. You can however create a helper function like this:

```
var hide = function(domEle) {
  domEle.style.display="none";
}
```

For you to be able to use your syntax, you may do the following:

- Create a Class that accepts array of dom elements. Or provide a function to add dom elements to the array.
- Add function hide to the above class Instead of each use forEach. each is not part of
  Javascript specification. Read MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Here is some basic code to do the same (I have not tested this for syntax errors):

```
function myLittleJQuery() {
  this._array = [];
}

myLittleJQuery.prototype = {
  add: function(domEle) {
    this._array.push(domEle);
  },

  hide: function() {
    this._array.forEach(function(domEle){
      domEle.style.display = "none";
    })
  }
}

//Usage
var my$ = new myLittleJQuery();
my$.add(someDomEle);
my$.add(someOtherDomEle);

my$.hide();
```

Comment: thank you, but how can i do this like class method, with each?

Answer (score 0):

```
Element.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.style.display="none";
};
```

You can extend individual DOM elements. Here we are adding the hide method to the prototype of Element. If I then did

```
document.querySelector("h2").hide();
```

The first h2 element on the page disappears.

This is adding the method onto individual dom elements. If you want to act on a collection of dom elements then you would have to extend the prototype of `NodeList` which is the type of object you get back if you do

```
document.querySelectorAll("h2");
```

One way to solve this problem would be to put the `hide` method on each DOM element. And then put a different `hide` method on the `NodeList`. Maybe something like this:

```
Element.prototype.hide = function() {
    this.style.display="none";
};

NodeList.prototype.hide = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this[i].hide();
    }
};
```

Adding those two methods would give you a flexible API that would let you call `hide` on either lists of elements or individual elements.

Then running

```
document.querySelectorAll("h2").hide();
```

Would hide all `h2` elements on the page.

This is not going to be supported in IE6-7. So if that is a problem for you then use jQuery.

Comment: Isn't extending existing JS Objects a bad idea? Read http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/104320/why-is-extending-the-dom-built-in-object-prototypes-a-bad-idea

Comment: I'm really just answering the actual question. If Adrian is interested in easy, cross browser, compatibility then he should probably just use jQuery. It sounds like he wants to play with the deeper constructs of JavaScript in the browser so who am I to judge?

Comment: respect your point. You may want to put a warning, to guide new programmers in right direction.

Comment: Honestly, there are some very well respected JavaScript peeps (Mootools springs to mind) that do DOM element extension. It's not an open or shut case. I think your answer and these comments should prove enough of a warning. At least people can read a bit further. You might want to see this dicussion yourself: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mootools-users/U4NmLOrQHFo

Comment: I belong to the set that believes in never adding function to existing prototypes. I don't use mootools. Just read right now, even the discussion there seems to be wishing for 2.0 to avoid prototype overrides. Looks like 2.0 got shelved. Also looked at another newer project from mootools called elements https://github.com/mootools/elements/blob/master/doc/elements.md. They have avoided it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to extend DOM elements then you can still use aychedee's code but define it as a function:

```
var hide = function() {
    if(! this)
      return null;
    var i;
    if(this.length){
      i=this.length;
      while(--i !== -1) {
        this[i].style.display="none";
      }
      return this;
    }
    this.style.display="none";
    return this;
};
hide.call(document.getElementById("someid"));
hide.call(document.getElementsByTagName("p"));
```